# How to rotate a circle colliding with a plane

Tags: math, 3d, physics, linear-algebra, collision

I have a very slim cylinder which I can approximate as a circle in a 3d room. This cylinder is moving through the room and I am currently trying to calculate collisions of this circle and a plane. I only look at small time frames and assume that the movement in each of these is linear. Also I do not have any gravity.

I know how to calculate the point where the circle is colliding the plane and know how to transform the movement vector (flip on plane surface). My question is how can I calculate a good looking rotation transformation for the circle after the collision?

Comment: Are you aware of the ways in which an object like a disc can tumble in 3D, even *without* a collision? It can involve some heavy mathematics.

Comment: The only thing I am calculating right now is the linear movement of the circle itself and the changing movement vector after a collision. As I said I don't want to take a self rotation of the disk into account and have no other forces in the example. I'm not sure if I am missing some important thing for the disks movement...

Comment: Wait... are you or are you not asking how to rotate the disc?

Comment: I only care about how the normal of the circles plane should be rotated upon a collision. Therefor I assume that the circle does not have a own rotation over time around it's center.

Comment: I have read your comment several times, and it seems to say _"I assume the circle will not rotate, and I want to know how its axis will rotate."_ This makes no sense to me. Perhaps there is a language barrier. I must bow out.

Comment: What I mean is that the circle has no rotation while traveling through the room without colliding with a wall. Upon a collision the movement direction changes and so should the circles orientation. So I am looking for a transformation of the circle's normal upon collision.